# PIC chip 16F690

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-construction, pic

im have problems writing some code on my PIC 16F690.
Im using the PIC C Compiler v4.099.

im trying to pass an int variable as an index to an array like this:

```
int myArray[2] = {20, 20};
int index = 0;
void myFunction()
{
    int iTest = myArray[index];
}
```

for some reason this code doesnt work, but when i replace the index in myArray[index] 
with a zero like this myArray[0], it works fine

Can anybody explain me what im doing wrong?
Greetz Rico

Comment: Can you explain us what "doesn't work" means?  Does it crash?  Give unexpected behavior?  Burn your toast?  Send you nasty emails?

Comment: Odds are excellent you meant to say that you were using the CCS compiler, not the PIC C Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

"index" is a built-in function on my compiler so that might be why it doesn't "work" in yours.

Comment: And here I was, only guessing... Glad to know that my guesses are not wholly inaccurate!

Answer (score 1):

In embedded programming, typically your C program is part of a greater whole which includes bootstrapping to properly reset the system to run your snipped of compiled C.

Is there any chance that in your programming environment, the name "index" is already reserved for some function, which is then walking past your array's length?

Comment: whenever i change it to another name it also doesnt work<
int iTest = myArray[index]; iTest is null
int iTest = myArray[0]; iTest is 20

Comment: What name did you change?  Your example uses the same name "index" as your problem.  Try using the name "bob" where you previously used "index" and see if it improves.  Rob's post tends to strengthen my argument that "index" is a macro, or a piece of text that gets expanded into other bits of text prior to compiling.  Odds are those "other bits of text" don't do what you want.

Comment: i have changed the index to a parcourindex but i dont see any improvement, it doesnt matter how i call it, it just doesnt work

Comment: if index is a poorly written macro, then it will expand if __anything__ contains the letters "index" in that order.  "parcourindex" may not have been a big enough change, change it to "parcour" and try again.

Comment: iTest is an int. How can it be "null" ? Do you mean it contains the value zero (0) ?